# Power BI Gantt 2.2.3 - remove Day when viewing Hour Date Type

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, gantt-chart, powerbi-custom-visuals

Using the [Power BI Gantt Chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380765) component from Microsoft, I'm able to render a daily schedule visualization pretty easily:

[image: Power BI Gantt Chart]

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to remove the day that is listed in parenthesis across the horizontal axis? I have the Date type set to "Hour".
2. Is there any way to change the font size of the horizontal axis so that I can fit the entire chart on one screen, without a scrollbar?